# recusrive algorithm for solving trees isomorphism?

Tags: java, class, recursion, nullpointerexception

I'm running code to check if two trees are isomorphic. They are isomorphic if one can be re-arranged to imitate the other. Only child nodes can be swapped, you can't swap a parent node with a child node or vice-versa or in any other way. And, null trees are isomorphic.

I have a small recursive code that first handles for null pointer errors. I then check if the nodes have the same int and if they do I call recursively every combination of their child nodes. The only time that it returns false, aside than on null cases, is when one of this combinations don't equal. Or at least that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here's what I have.(Note: I use null pointer exception because I have to work with a node object).

```
class GfG
{
    public boolean isIsomorphic(Node root1,Node root2)
    {
        boolean a, b;
        a = b = false;
        int i;
        try{
            i = root1.data;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ex){
            a = true;
        }
        try{
            i = root2.data;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ex){
            b = true;
        }
        if(a == true & b == true){
            return true;
        }
        else if((a == false & b == true) | (b ==false & a ==true)){
            return false;
        } 
        else {
            if(root1.data == root2.data){
                isIsomorphic(root1.left, root2.left);
                isIsomorphic(root1.right, root2.right);
                isIsomorphic(root1.left, root2.right);
                isIsomorphic(root1.right, root2.left);                
                return true;
                }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the object Node has and int as attribute that it's passed on to and initialized to, and two child nodes initialized to null.
(There's is such a case where they can be initialized to null, hence the null exception).

I'm supposed to return false in this case, but return true, I have no idea why though

```
0 1 L 0 2 R  1 3 L 1 4 R  2 5 L 2 6 R  3 7 L 3 8 R  4 9 L 4 10 R  5 11 L 5 12 R  6 13 L 6 14 R

0 3 L 0 0 R  3 6 L 3 14 R  0 4 L 0 11 R  6 8 L 6 9 R  14 1 L 14 14 R  4 10 L 4 13 R  11 14 L 11 1 R
```

Comment: There's a few bugs in that code. For example, your recursive calls to `isIsomorphic` don't cause the return value to change. I haven't worked it through, but you might want `return isIsomorphic() && isIsomorphic() && ...`.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for your reply. The return varies based on the values not on the function itself, so the only time it should return true is when the nodes match, but something is getting through that I can't see.

Comment: So what's the purpose of calling isIsomorphic recursively? The return values of the recursive calls are ignored, and the methods are pure (no side effects), so it's pointless to call them. I think you need to "or" the return values, so if all the nodes are the same, then it's isomorphic. And you're still missing the idea that nodes can be in any order: currently you're trying and failing to check that they're in a specific order...

Comment: I see now, I finally got it to work! thanks for the note, I'll keep better track of my recursive methods from now on.